# Adding on different forms VB

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm new to using VB. I'm sure there is a way to do what i'm looking for but i'm just not sure how to do it.

Form1
      x = 6 + 8

Form2 
      y = 8 + 7

```
 label1.text = x + y
```

Not sure how to carry the x value from form 1 to form 2
( Declared x as public integer)

also the x value changes everytime i run my program so i can't declare it's value in a modual ... i don't think

Basically timer starts counting down 
- hit stop it adds the current time to a label 
- goes to next form 
- on the the next form how do i get the label to display the same value that the label had in form 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a module, on the module write

```
Dim x As Integer = 0 'or double, depending on your datatype
Dim y As Integer = 0
Dim res As Integer = 0

Public Sub setVar(ByVal var1 As Integer, Byval Var2 As Integer, ByVal whatVar As String)
   If whatVar = "y" Then
      y = var1 + var2
   ElseIf whatVar = "x" Then
      x = var1 + var2
   End If
End Sub

Public Function getResult() As Integer
   res = x + y
   return res
End Function
```

Usage:

on Form1,

```
setVar(6,8, "x")
```

on Form2,

```
setVar(8,7,"y")
```

on the label,

```
label1.Text = getResult().ToString
```

Haven't tested the code, but it should work :)